# How can I optimize this func and remove code line?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this func and how can I optimize this func using Object.keys(arr) to remove code line or get an optimization?

```
convertTime(diffTime): object {
    let timer = {
      days: Math.floor(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)),
      hours: Math.floor((diffTime % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)),
      minutes: Math.floor((diffTime % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)),
      second: Math.floor((diffTime % (1000 *60) /(1000))),
    }
    if (timer.days <= 9) {
      timer.days.toString() === '0' + timer.days;
    }
    if (timer.hours <= 9) {
      timer.hours.toString() === '0' + timer.hours;
    }
    if (timer.minutes <= 9) {
      timer.minutes.toString() === '0' + timer.minutes;
    }
    if (timer.second <= 9) {
      timer.second.toString() === '0' + timer.second;
    }
    return timer;
  }
```

Comment: Your current code is not doing anything at all in the `if`s - you only have orphaned expressions there, not assignments

Comment: Is that the official term @CertainPerformance? I've heard that used before, but didn't really know what it meant.

Comment: @JackBashford No (at least I don't think so), it's just the phrase I always use for it that gets the point across concisely, there may be a more official / better one

Comment: I use this func for converttime, and my co-worker comment that I should use Object.keys(arr) instead, but I dont know how to use this func (Object.keys(arr))

Comment: is there any different way that can I write to remove that hard code using object.keys(arr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the use of `Object.keys()` her would be:

```js
convertTime(diffTime): object {
    let timer = {
      days: Math.floor(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)),
      hours: Math.floor((diffTime % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)),
      minutes: Math.floor((diffTime % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)),
      second: Math.floor((diffTime % (1000 *60) /(1000))),
    }
    Object.keys(timer).forEach(key => {
        if (timer[key] <= 9) {
            timer[key].toString() === '0' + timer[key];
        }
    });
    return timer;
}
```

(assuming these `if`s do anything, which I doubt as @CertainPerformance commented, and I don't think that's the best solution here, @mbojko's answer is better, but it's what your colleague is looking for)

Comment: timer[key] = '0${timer[key]}'; I use that one instead  timer[key].toString() === '0' + timer[key];  no need toString ?? both are work!

Comment: The fact that the second option works confuses me, `timer[key] = '0${timer[key]}';` works but it makes the value associated to that key a string, and `Math.floor()` returns a number, so you may have an array with both numbers and string in it which is not advisable, I would go with only string (`Object.keys(timer).forEach(key => timer[key] = timer[key] > 9 ? '${timer[key]}' : '0${timer[key]}');`)

Answer (score 1):

There's a function for padding strings to required length: String.prototype.padStart. Just do

```
    return {
      days: Math.floor(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)).toString().padStart(2, '0'),
      hours: Math.floor((diffTime % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)).toString().padStart(2, '0'),
      minutes: Math.floor((diffTime % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60)).toString().padStart(2, '0'),
      second: Math.floor((diffTime % (1000 *60) /(1000))).toString().padStart(2, '0'),
    }
```

Comment: padStart does not exist on type string

Comment: Internet Explorer, by any chance?